# Getting an error that secondController is not registered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Hi Im trying to write an angular app from scratch. (New to it) Keep getting an error that **secondController is not registered**. Why?

These are my three files and for some reason it keeps saying "The controller with the name 'secondController' is not registered."

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="./angular.js"></script>
    <script src="./secondModule.js"></script>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="appController">
       <p>App text : {{myAppText}}</p>

       <p>secondControllerModule: {{ secondControllerText }}</p>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="secondController">
        Second Module : {{secondControllerText}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
 angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller("appController",["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.myAppText = "Hello, I am appController text"

}])
```

**secondModule.js**

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller("secondController",["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.secondControllerText = "Hello, I am seasdfsdfasdfacond   Controller Text"
}])
```

Comment: AngularJS team officially announced end of support on 2021, so I would recommend to go with Angular (8 atm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think as per your code you should take three files
 1. Declare angular module in module.js file

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

2. Add the first controller appController.js

   app.controller("appController",["$scope", function($scope){

   $scope.myAppText = "Hello, I am appController text";

   }]);
3. Add second controller file secondController.js

   app.controller("secondController",["$scope", function($scope){
         $scope.secondControllerText = "Hello, I am seasdfsdfasdfacond   Controller Text";
      }]);

now put them in this heirarchy
- Add ref of Angular JS
then 
1 `module.js`
2 `appController.js`
3 `secondController.js`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to clarify that this is incorrect:

```
 <div ng-controller="appController">
           <p>App text : {{myAppText}}</p>

           <p>secondControllerModule: {{ secondControllerText }}</p>// Defined in the wrong ng-controller, 
so move it to the correct one.
        </div>
```

The reason you are getting that error is that you're defining the app module twice in your js files. It's rather simple, all you need to do is take off the second parameter in your **secondModule.js**

```
angular.module("myApp")// Needs to be like this

.controller("secondController",["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.secondControllerText = "Hello, I am seasdfsdfasdfacond   Controller Text"
}])
```

Then in your **app.js file**

```
angular.module("myApp", [])

.controller("appController",["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.myAppText = "Hello, I am appController text"

}])
```

Then in your HTML file, you need to fix the order of the script

```
  <script src="./angular.js"></script>
<script src="./app.js"></script> // App module must be first because the module is defined here
  <script src="./secondModule.js"></script>
```